# Join or Mutible DBContext Repository Generic c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, repository-pattern

I have repository generic where I do method as Get,Update,Insert.

I get a data from table in data base I use this method.

```
 public IEnumerable<typeEntity> Get<typeEntity>(Expression<Func<typeEntity, bool>> newObjectEntity,int page, int rowsByPage) where typeEntity : class
    {
       List<typeEntity> Result = null;
            Result = Context.Set<typeEntity>().Where(newObjectEntity).OrderBy(m => true).Skip<typeEntity>(5 * (page - 1)).Take<typeEntity>(rowsByPage).ToList<typeEntity>();
        return Result;
    }
```

I when get data only a one table this is my code:

```
var collecProducts = repository.Get<Products>(c => true);
```

My problem is when I want get two tablet How I do this?. I find this code but is very slow.

```
var collecProducts = repository.Get<Products>(c => true);
var collecCategory = repository.Get<Category>(c => true);

var collectProductToCategory = (from p in collecProducts
                                           join c in collecCategory on p.idCategory equals c.idCategory).ToList();
```

The problem this code is that get all data de products and category and I want from SQL Server only data necessary for example as join TSQL.

```
select p.idProducts from products p join category c on p.idCategory = c.idCategory
```

In conclusion How I could get data use join since repository generyc.

Comment: this code looks much like the code generated by entity framework when importing a stored procedure. if you want to perform a join, regardless of your implementation you will have to have the correct object. here is a simple example from Microsoft on how to write a left outer join, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins, but also contains a more in-depth list of other LINQ functions.

Answer (score 0):

I find a form get this result for example Product and Category in repository Generic through include.

```
 public IEnumerable<typeEntity> Get<typeEntity>(Expression<Func<typeEntity, bool>> newObjectEntity,int page, int rowsByPage, string include) where typeEntity : class
    {
       List<typeEntity> Result = null;
            Result = Context.Set<typeEntity>().Where(newObjectEntity).include(include).OrderBy(m => true).Skip<typeEntity>(5 * (page - 1)).Take<typeEntity>(rowsByPage).ToList<typeEntity>();
        return Result;
    }
```

With include you can string for example Product->Category and get this object.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you found is slow because the repository method is materializing/executing the query immediately instead of allowing deferred execution to occur. Try removing the ".ToList()" from the query within the repository method:

```
public IEnumerable<typeEntity> Get<typeEntity>(Expression<Func<typeEntity, bool>> newObjectEntity,int page, int rowsByPage) where typeEntity : class
{
   IEnumerable<typeEntity> Result = null;
        Result = Context.Set<typeEntity>().Where(newObjectEntity).OrderBy(m => true).Skip<typeEntity>(5 * (page - 1)).Take<typeEntity>(rowsByPage);
    return Result;
}
```

This will allow you to compose and construct higher order queries without pulling the whole table into memory immediately.

Comment: Replace IEnumerable with IQueryable. Only in this case queries will be effective.